# Matlab help to read multiple file images and save the final image to directory

Tags: matlab, file, matlab-figure, facial-identification

im trying to do some facial recognition as im currently trying to figure out an idea i want to put in place

Ive never had to read multiple images from a folder before and i gave it my best shot but have come across an error that i cant seem to work ou

```
myPath = 'C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Msc Computer Science\CN7023\CW\Faces_easy\';
a = dir(fullfile(myPath, '*.jpg'));
fileName = arrayfun( @(x) fullfile( myPath, x.name ), a, 'UniformOutput', false );
for k = 1:length(fileName)
    I = imread(fileName{k});
end


// Code to add in
    files = dir('C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Msc Computer Science\CN7023\CW\Faces_easy\*.jpg');
    files_len = numel(files);

    result = cell(files_len,2);

    for ii = 1:files_len
        file = fullfile(files(ii).folder,files(ii).name);
        img = imread(file);
        result(ii,:) = {file perform_analysis(img)}; % or whatever your function is called
    end

//

faceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();
bbox=step(faceDetect,I);
face=imcrop(I,bbox);
centerx=size(face,1)/2+bbox(1);
centery=size(face,2)/2+bbox(2);
eyeDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('RightEye');
eyebox=step(eyeDetect,face);
n=size(eyebox,1);
e=[];
for it=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if (j > it)
          if ((abs(eyebox(j,2)-eyebox(it,2))<68)&& (abs(eyebox(j,1)-eyebox(it,1))>40))
            e(1,:)=eyebox(it,:);
            e(2,:)=eyebox(j,:);
            d=1;break;
          end
        end
    end
    if(d == 1)
        break;
    end
end
eyebox(1,:)=e(1,:);
eyebox(2,:)=e(2,:);
c=eyebox(1,3)/2;
d=eyebox(1,4)/2;
eyeCenter1x=eyebox(1,1)+c+bbox(1);
eyeCenter1y=eyebox(1,2)+d+bbox(2);
e=eyebox(2,3)/2;
f=eyebox(2,4)/2;
eyeCenter2x=eyebox(2,1)+e+bbox(1);
eyeCenter2y=eyebox(2,2)+f+bbox(2);
ndetect=vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Nose','MergeThreshold',16);
nosebox=step(ndetect,face);
noseCenterx=nosebox(1,1)+(nosebox(1,3)/2)+bbox(1);
noseCentery=nosebox(1,2)+(nosebox(1,4)/2);
m=[1,noseCentery,size(face,1),((size(face,2))-noseCentery)];
mouth=imcrop(face,m);

mdetect=vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Mouth','MergeThreshold' ,20);
mouthbox=step(mdetect,mouth);
for it=1:size(mouthbox,1)
    if(mouthbox(it,2)>20)
        mouthbox(1,:)=mouthbox(it,:);
        break;
    end
end
mouthbox(1,2)=mouthbox(1,2)+noseCentery;
noseCentery=noseCentery+bbox(2);
mouthCenterx=mouthbox(1,1)+(mouthbox(1,3)/2)+bbox(1);
mouthCentery=mouthbox(1,2)+(mouthbox(1,4)/2)+bbox(2);
shape=[centerx centery;eyeCenter1x eyeCenter1y;eyeCenter2x eyeCenter2y;noseCenterx noseCentery;mouthCenterx mouthCentery];
imshow(I);
hold on;
plot(shape(:,1),shape(:,2),'+','MarkerSize',10);

eyebox(1,1:2)=eyebox(1,1:2)+bbox(1,1:2);
eyebox(2,1:2)=eyebox(2,1:2)+bbox(1,1:2);
nosebox(1,1:2)=nosebox(1,1:2)+bbox(1,1:2);
mouthbox(1,1:2)=mouthbox(1,1:2)+bbox(1,1:2);
all_points=[eyebox(1,:);eyebox(2,:);nosebox(1,:);mouthbox(1,:)];
dpoints=size(all_points,1);
label=cell(dpoints,1);
i=1;

for i = 1: dpoints
label{i}= num2str(i);
end

videoout=insertObjectAnnotation(I,'rectangle',all_points,label,'TextBoxOpacity',0.3,'Fontsize',9);
imshow(videoout);hold on;plot(shape(:,1),shape(:,2),'+','MarkerSize',10);

dt=delaunayTriangulation(shape(:,1),shape(:,2));
imshow(videoout);hold on;triplot(dt);hold off
```

So i have changed it to what i currently have and it works but only on the last image, i want to make it do it on all images in a folder... I have 435 images in the folder it is calling, i dont want to all open as a figure once done, i would like them to save to a certain folder or workspace if that is possible

Answer (score 0):

Print "fileName{k}" to verify if you are getting the required path for file. 
secondly do not update fileName inside loop, you need to use different variable here inside loop.

Comment: i have printed the file and it is showing the 1st file name, but not any other. Okay so i would delete fileName = ... ??

Comment: i have deleted that line and ran the code but it only opens the very last image in the folder, so its readin all of them but only opening the last one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform your analysis on every image, you have to put your logics inside the loop itself and collect their result into a cell array or something across the lines. For instance, you can also simplify your folder search:

```
files = dir('C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Msc Computer Science\CN7023\CW\Faces_easy\*.jpg');
files_len = numel(files);

result = cell(files_len,2);

for ii = 1:files_len
    file = fullfile(files(ii).folder,files(ii).name);
    img = imread(file);
    result(ii,:) = {file perform_analysis(img)}; % or whatever your function is called
end
```

Once this is done, every row of the `result` variable will contain the file name in the first column and the analysis outcome in the second column.

**EDIT**

```
files = dir('C:\Users\Callum\Desktop\Msc Computer Science\CN7023\CW\Faces_easy\*.jpg');
files_len = numel(files);

for ii = 1:files_len
    file = fullfile(files(ii).folder,files(ii).name);
    I = imread(file);

    faceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();
    bbox=step(faceDetect,I);
    face=imcrop(I,bbox);
    centerx=size(face,1)/2+bbox(1);
    centery=size(face,2)/2+bbox(2);
    eyeDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('RightEye');
    eyebox=step(eyeDetect,face);
    n=size(eyebox,1);
    e=[];
    for it=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if (j > it)
          if ((abs(eyebox(j,2)-eyebox(it,2))<68)&& (abs(eyebox(j,1)-eyebox(it,1))>40))
        e(1,:)=eyebox(it,:);
        e(2,:)=eyebox(j,:);
        d=1;break;
          end
        end
    end
    if(d == 1)
        break;
    end
    end
    eyebox(1,:)=e(1,:);
    eyebox(2,:)=e(2,:);
    c=eyebox(1,3)/2;
    d=eyebox(1,4)/2;
    eyeCenter1x=eyebox(1,1)+c+bbox(1);
    eyeCenter1y=eyebox(1,2)+d+bbox(2);
    e=eyebox(2,3)/2;
    f=eyebox(2,4)/2;
    eyeCenter2x=eyebox(2,1)+e+bbox(1);
    eyeCenter2y=eyebox(2,2)+f+bbox(2);
    ndetect=vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Nose','MergeThreshold',16);
    nosebox=step(ndetect,face);
    noseCenterx=nosebox(1,1)+(nosebox(1,3)/2)+bbox(1);
    noseCentery=nosebox(1,2)+(nosebox(1,4)/2);
    m=[1,noseCentery,size(face,1),((size(face,2))-noseCentery)];
    mouth=imcrop(face,m);

    mdetect=vision.CascadeObjectDetector('Mouth','MergeThreshold' ,20);
    mouthbox=step(mdetect,mouth);
    for it=1:size(mouthbox,1)
    if(mouthbox(it,2)>20)
        mouthbox(1,:)=mouthbox(it,:);
        break;
    end
    end
    mouthbox(1,2)=mouthbox(1,2)+noseCentery;
    noseCentery=noseCentery+bbox(2);
    mouthCenterx=mouthbox(1,1)+(mouthbox(1,3)/2)+bbox(1);
    mouthCentery=mouthbox(1,2)+(mouthbox(1,4)/2)+bbox(2);
    shape=[centerx centery;eyeCenter1x eyeCenter1y;eyeCenter2x eyeCenter2y;noseCenterx noseCentery;mouthCenterx mouthCentery];
    imshow(I);
    hold on;
    plot(shape(:,1),shape(:,2),'+','MarkerSize',10);

    eyebox(1,1:2)=eyebox(1,1:2)+bbox(1,1:2);
    eyebox(2,1:2)=eyebox(2,1:2)+bbox(1,1:2);
    nosebox(1,1:2)=nosebox(1,1:2)+bbox(1,1:2);
    mouthbox(1,1:2)=mouthbox(1,1:2)+bbox(1,1:2);
    all_points=[eyebox(1,:);eyebox(2,:);nosebox(1,:);mouthbox(1,:)];
    dpoints=size(all_points,1);
    label=cell(dpoints,1);
    i=1;

    for i = 1: dpoints
    label{i}= num2str(i);
    end

    videoout=insertObjectAnnotation(I,'rectangle',all_points,label,'TextBoxOpacity',0.3,'Fontsize',9);
    imshow(videoout);hold on;plot(shape(:,1),shape(:,2),'+','MarkerSize',10);

    dt=delaunayTriangulation(shape(:,1),shape(:,2));
    imshow(videoout);hold on;triplot(dt);hold off
end
```

Comment: Okay ive made changed to the question, to what i already have, so with what you just gave me i would take out the top lines and replace that? what function would i call?

Comment: You put everything from `faceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();` to the end of the script inside the first loop.

Comment: sorry im not great at this, any chance you can edit my code to do what you mean ?

Comment: Thank you so much!! also is it possible to do gender recognition from images?

Comment: Tommaso this is giving me an error on noseCenterx=nosebox(1,1)+(nosebox(1,3)/2)+bbox(1); The 2 errors are.                                                             
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in allfacetestmultiple (line 45)
    noseCenterx=nosebox(1,1)+(nosebox(1,3)/2)+bbox(1);

Comment: From your code I cannot say what happens since it's not reproductible. But overall I think we are diverging too much from the original question. You should open a new one to address the issues concerning image analysis, which is something I'm not really into.